# pass some value to winscp script from perl

Tags: perl

Am creating one script to pass multiple file to winscp script through perl  like i have 10 file in my folder i need to pass each one file to winscp script,

```
$get='file.txt';
#system('winscp.com /ini=nul /command "open sftp://c400597:Pandi@123@dev/ - hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 5c:07:0d:9f:c6:dd:41:62:b5:0a:e6:0c:c3:7a:94:2d""" "put $get" "exit"');

system('winscp.com /ini=nul /command "open sftp://c400597:Pandi@123@dev/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 5c:07:0d:9f:c6:dd:41:62:b5:0a:e6:0c:c3:7a:94:2d""" "put $get" "exit"');
print "above statement executed 0\n";
#system('winscp.com /ini=nul /command "open sftp://c400597:Pandi@123@dev/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 5c:07:0d:9f:c6:dd:41:62:b5:0a:e6:0c:c3:7a:94:2d"""');
#print "above statement executed 1\n";
#system('winscp.com /ini=nul /command "put "'.$get);
#print "above statement executed 2\n";
system ('winscp.com /ini=nul /command "exit"');
print "above statement executed 3\n";
#winscp.com /ini=nul /command "open sftp://user:password@example.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"""
# "get examplefile.txt d:\" "exit"
#system("$x." ".$y." ".$z") || die "cannot open";
#
}
closedir $db;
```

i need to pass $get variable to that winscp script.

I have tired several method to achieve this requirement but i cannot complete it could anyone help me?

Comment: Have you really encoded your username and password in the URL that you've posted on the internet? But it might be that you've got an `@` in your password that's causing the problem.

Comment: thanks for  you reply, i have tired the same code for one file name(hard code) it was works fine